# usereducer won't update state

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer, ionic-react

I am very new to React and come across useReducer.
If I paste my code here, it will be very long, because it involve component, useContext and useReducer.So I will paste some of the code only.
I have question about the state in try and catch loop.
My reducer fire up a login method that use firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword(). Am I doing the try and catch loop wrong? I am able to see the error message in the console.log, but my state won't update with the error message, neither in the then().catch() nor in the try and catch loop.

```
  const loginUser = (usename, password, state) => {
    try{

      const res = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then( user => {
          return {...state, userid: user.uid}
        }).catch(error => {
              return {...state, error: error.message}
        })


    }catch (error) {
      console.log("oops !! error: ", error);
   
      return {...state, error: error, isLoggedIn:false, isLoading:false};
    }
}

export const storeReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case USER_LOGIN: 
      
        return loginUser(action.username, action.password, state);
          
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

The code above is a simplified version that I am facing problem with updating the state using useReducer.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `loginUser` function to something like this...

```
const loginUser = async (usename, password, state) => {
    try{
      const response = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

      return // return user here
    }catch (error) {
      console.log("oops !! error: ", error);
   
      return // return error here
    }
}
```

And you should dispatch an *action* based on the return of this function, or dispatch from this function. You should **NOT** place this function within your reducer as it is asynchronous, and your reducer should be a *pure function*

It should be more like...

```
loginUser.then(data => {
  // dispatch accordingly
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason for the reply. I did the changes accordingly but it return  Promise..How do I handle the Promise ? How do I get the value returned by the Promise ?

Comment: May I ask what are you returning? Or what code do you have after _awaiting_ response?

Comment: It returned the Promise with the correct state value, but the state value is not updated to the useContext value. Promise state value show at https://i.ibb.co/KmxLjx0/Promise.png  while the context value is shown at https://i.ibb.co/RzZtw6g/Context.png

Comment: Hi Jason, the async await cause delay in getting the state. I tried many different approach using try/catch and async/await but to no avail. The state update is delayed in the useReducer when I use async/await and it returned initial state in useReducer. So,I switch to normal try/catch without async/await but add-in the `const currentUser = auth.currentUser` after the  `const response =  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)`. And it give me the result I wish to see.. Anyway, Thanks for your effort to help